# Check if a date belongs to a given month and year in python

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a built-in python function where I would check a given date if it belongs to a month and year. For example I would like to check if a date 05/15/2019 belongs to  05/2019 month and year. I've created a function where I split the date then match its month and year to 05/2019. I would just like to know if there is a built-in function

Comment: Yea, if you convert your date string to a datetime object, you can just do `date.month == 5 and date.year == 2019` https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html never manipulate data such as dates or times or paths as strings, always use a library.

Answer (score 0):

Pasting a function, which we use in our project, if helpful

```
def is_in_month(test_date, month_start_end={}):
    """
    Check to see if the date falls within the last month. Expects a dict with
    start and end properties.
    """
    if not month_start_end.get("start") or not month_start_end.get("end"):
        raise ValueError("Need a dict. with start and end")

    if month_start_end.get("start").tzinfo is not None and month_start_end.get("start").tzinfo.utcoffset(month_start_end.get("start")) is not None:
        return month_start_end.get("start") <= pytz.UTC.localize(test_date) <= month_start_end.get("end")
    return month_start_end.get("start") <= test_date <= month_start_end.get("end")
```